# defining button inside jQuery template

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-templates

I am trying to display a button using jQuery template. The code is as below:

```
 <script id="EmailContainerTemplate" type="text/html">
    <div><a href="mailto:${EMailAddress}" data-role="button">${EMailAddress}</a></div>
 </script>
```

The target div is defined as:

```
<div id="EmailContainer" class="center-wrapper"> </div>
```

And the template binding code:

```
$("#EmailContainer").append($("#EmailContainerTemplate").tmpl(contact));
```

But it is displaying as hyperlink. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger `create` event on your new markup

```
$( ...new markup that contains widgets... ).appendTo( ".ui-page" ).trigger( "create" );
```

Refer to [Enhancing New markup Section](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html)